# Renting Virtual Machines for testing

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

I am looking for renting virtual machines for testing my desktop software. In particular, I am interested in all modern Windows client versions (XP no SP, SP1, SP2, SP3, Vista with/without SP1/2, Windows 7), also a couple of Linux distros and of course a MacOS X - but that's hardly possible. There are plenty of virtual servers for rent but they're all running Windows Servers of different kinds, and I need XP's and Vista's. Of course I can do that locally but this requires building the infrastructure and buying licenses, which takes time & money. So any pointers here?

**EDIT:** Found [VMBed.com](http://www.vmbed.com) but they only offer XP and not Vistas - but already better than nothing.

**EDIT2:** Was pointed to [BrowserCam](http://www.browsercam.com) - will try them out and post here, for now they look promising but a very ugly website.

Comment: Try [Oracle Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It's free, but you will need the CDs or ISOs to install your Windows. You could have many VPS on your desktop. [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) can automate Virtual Box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For testing browsers you can use the browsercam service (http://www.browsercam.com/Default2.aspx)

This might allow you to do the other testing you require too using their remote access option.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I will try them out, I only wish they had a better website - the current one is absolutely terrible.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, sorry. Point is - most people HAVE the infrastructure and do not need any licenses (AS: using MSDN is cheaper than buying things anyway, and MSDN has all the licenses for testing anyway).

I know of no shop tha trents out short term virtual machines for testing and keeps a larger variance of them ready in different patch states (which is what you would need).

I suggest you get a local server...
* AMD based (all support hyper-v)
* 16gb RAM (cheap, fits on a micro-atx board)

Install Server 2008 R2 on it, Hyper-V, some large dist and use your MSDN licenses.

Comment: Well that doesn't work really well for a small startup company - but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why not? Small startup = Bizspark = MSDN for 100 USD for three years...? http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/ - Microsoft REALLY throws that stuff away to get it out. Even if not - the price of a MSDN is ridiculously low.

Comment: Not because of pricing but mostly because of configuration/setting up effort - I'd rather outsource the duty of setting up and keep all that stuff running rather than do it myself. But agree, not that expensive.

Comment: That wont work. See - the poblem is that you need a VERY specific envirnoment. Lots of prepared machines in specific patch states. Plus the capability to set up your own when a customer calls with a problem. This is a lot of overhead unless you can cut it down, and only you can do that. I have such a small library for my own development.

There is no market because basically all dev shops have different requirements and do maintain their own infrastructure.

Comment: Yes and no. When you're building say a web app or an Adobe AIR desktop app like I am doing, you need quite a few very standard options: different windows plus different browsers, totalling maybe in 15-20 combinations maximum - and that's for everyone. Of course if you're building a large native windows application, it's all different, I agree - but at least for web applications it's all manageable I think.

Comment: Fo browsers you dont need virtual desktops... you need browsers.

Check: http://browsershots.org/ and.... http://www.spoon.net/browsers/ for a method to run all browsers on one computer without complete virualization and without desktop ;)

Comment: You might only need 15 to 20 machines, but the configuratios are very specific. What you're asking for is 15 out of thousands of possible confirutaions. Finding a rentalshop that provides those thousands to choose from isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

For cross-browser or multiple browser testing, look at:

- [LitmusApp](http://litmusapp.com/) (sponsor [DocType](http://doctype.com/) of the [LoJ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/))
- [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) (free)
- [BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/) (adobe)
- as well a [few other solutions](http://designm.ag/resources/cross-browser-testing/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips, I need this too - extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The problem your going to have with getting VPS's with desktop OS, is that the providers will need to use SPLA licencing to lincennce the OS and I do not think it is possible to licence desktop OS's using SPLA.

I would suggest you get your self an MSDN subscription, purchase a  mid range server, nothing fancy, with a load of RAM, install ESXi and setup a load of VM's that meet the spec you want. Yes you may have ot outlay more initially, but it will save you significant costs on VPS's on a monthly basis, and it means you have the setup there, ready to use when you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, of course custom server is a solution - just wanted something with zero up-front cost. Valid point about SPLA licensing though.